# Hubspot associations API giving me empty contacts

Tags: node.js, hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-api

I tried asking this on the hubspot community but my question there gets automatically marked as spam, so I'll try my luck here.

I'm using the **@hubspot/api-client** v8.1.0 package for NodeJS. Here is a piece of code I'm using to test getting contacts associated to deals:

```
const deals = await Api.dealsByStage('Grundbuchdaten Hinzugefügt', 1000, 100, _ => true);
const contacts: Record<string, any> = {};

for (let deal of deals) {
    console.log(`Processing deal ${deal.id}`);
    const dealContacts = await Api.client.crm.deals.associationsApi.getAll(deal.id, 'contact');
    contacts[deal.id] = dealContacts.results;
}

await fs.writeFile('./sample.json', JSON.stringify(contacts, null, 2));
```

The `Api.dealsByStage` function on top is a function I wrote that gets a list of deals (in this case it gets the top 1000 deals). That works fine because I can see the `for` loop looping through each deal ID, and also I already use the function on other parts of the code with no issues.

But the call to `associationsApi.getAll` is the one acting weird. I do get a list of either 0, 1 or 2 empty objects (with no properties, not even the contact ID). If I was getting an empty list of contacts I guess it could be that the deals have no associated contacts, but I'm actually getting something back. Here are a few of the results I get:

```
"5336323558": [],
"5336234188": [
  {}
],
"5336291063": [
  {},
  {}
],
"5336870390": [],
```

I also tried using the "contacs" (with an "s") object type but got the same results. Am I using the wrong API or doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles into this, the issue wasn't in the associations API, the problem was that at some point I updated to the latest version of the Node API, which also uses a newer version of Hubspot API which is completely different from the one before.

I just downgraded `@hubspot/api-client` to version 7.1.2 and how everything works fine.